# Uploading images to Amazon S3 gives "The file indicated by the file path does not exist."

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, file-upload

I am currently working on a social networking site.  When a user uploads an image on their profile, the image would be sent to my amazon bucket.

After my implementation there is always an error during image upload request that says

> The file indicated by the file path does not exist.

Below is my implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void Upload_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream Photo = ImageUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;

    string name = Path.GetFileName(ImageUpload.FileName);
    string Bucket = "forevayoung19";
    string url = "";
    string File = @name;
    bool Image;
    Image = Upload.SendImage(Photo, Bucket, url, File, UserName);
    if (Image == true)
    {
        Response.Write("successfully uploaded");

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Error");
    }
}

public bool SendImage(System.IO.Stream photo, string bucket, string url, string file, string UserName)
{
    var client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
    var utility = new TransferUtility(client);
    var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

    if (url == "" || url == null)
    {
        request.BucketName = bucket;
    }
    else
    {   
        request.BucketName = bucket + @"/" + url;
    }

    request.Key = UserName;
    request.FilePath = file;
    request.InputStream = photo;
    request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite;
    utility.Upload(request); ///Error on this line

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: It's setted your photo var, two lines before the error?

Comment: Which line is generating the error? What is `ImageUpload`? Why is the `Upload_click` function not using `sender` or `e`?

Comment: The line generating the error is near the last line where is says utility.upload(request).  ImageUpload is a name using the file upload control .  Upload_click is what is clicked when the file is in the upload control to send to aws.